# How would one run two controllers at the same time AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a webapp in AngularJS (using Yeoman), and I have a loop to add 1 to a counter every second. This worked fine, until I needed multiple tabs with multiple controllers. I tried running a loop in the main controller, but this didn't work.

I want the gameLoop function in MoneyCtrl to run at all times, is there a better place to put this function?

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do this, or at least achieve the same effect?

[Github project](https://github.com/ducky11423/incremental)

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple controllers running simultaneously, nested or side by side. Please show your HTML and JS. If it's as simple as a loop and counter, you may only need a Service or Directive depending on the details. What problem are you trying to solve with the counter, maybe there is an alternative solution.

Comment: Can you  show us some code and the stage where you are facing difficulty

Comment: Added Github link, sorry.

Comment: The code must be in the question itself, not at github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the gameLoop function on the [run](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks) block.

```
angular.module('incrementalApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource',
    'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngTouch'
]).config(function($routeProvider) {
    //...
}).run(function($rootScope, MoneyService, Vars){

    var stop;

    $rootScope.loop = function() {
        if (angular.isDefined(stop) ) {
            return;
        }
        stop = $interval(function() {
            angular.forEach(Vars.clickers, function(clicker){
                MoneyService.addMoney((clicker.amount * clicker.production)/Vars.fps);
            });

        }, 1000/Vars.fps);

        $rootScope.stopLoop = function() {
            if (angular.isDefined(stop)) {
                $interval.cancel(stop);
                stop = undefined;
            }
        };

        $rootScope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
          $scope.stopFight();
        });
    };  

$scope.loop();
})
```

And use a service to add the money so you can require the service on each controller.

Comment: I have added this to the app.js, but now when I open it the Money view doesn't load.

Comment: Is there any error? This should not affect the controller's view rendering.

Comment: Yes sorry, The service had a capital in it. Thank you for your help.